# Applescript - spctl --status

Tags: applescript

I would like to toggle between Enable/Disable in my applescript command. Can't seem to identify what's wrong with this script. It's not switching its states (toggling) when I run the same command again:

if {"disabled"} contains (do shell script "spctl --status") then
    set theAllow to "enable"
else
    set theAllow to "disable"
end if
do shell script (("sudo spctl --master-" & theAllow) as string) with administrator privileges

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCjsX.png)

Comment: When you run (do shell script "spctl --status") what does it return? I got "assessments enabled". I think you need to modify the string in your list to match what's been returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source cod](https://opensource.apple.com/source/security_systemkeychain/security_systemkeychain-55105/src/spctl.cpp)e for `spctl`, the `spctl --status` *command* will either return `assessments enabled` or `assessments disabled`. However, if it's *disabled*, then `do shell script "spctl --status"` exits with `error "assessments disabled" number 1` and you'll need to account for it in some manner.

```
do shell script "spctl --status"
    --> error "assessments disabled" number 1
```

So, to keep things simple, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* simply toggles the *state* of `spctl` based on it *status*:

```
if (do shell script "spctl --status; exit 0") is "assessments disabled" then
    do shell script "spctl --master-enable" with administrator privileges
else
    do shell script "spctl --master-disable" with administrator privileges
end if
```

Example output when `spctl` is disabled while using `; exit 0` to handle `error "assessments disabled" number 1`:

```
do shell script "spctl --status; exit 0"
    --> "assessments disabled"
do shell script "spctl --master-enable" with administrator privileges
```

As you can see, by using `; exit 0` after `spctl --status`, it stops  `error "assessments disabled" number 1` and allows the script to proceed.

There certainly is more then one way to trap the *error*, however, this *example* **AppleScript** *code*, that simply toggles the *state* of `spctl`, I've shown is simple and straight forward without the need to be more verbose with its *error handling*.

Otherwise you'll have to code it in a different manner, using a `try` *statement* wrapped around the `do shell script "spctl --status` *command* and an `on error` *handler*.

Comment: @Jenny David I'm glad it worked for you and appreciate the thanks, however, please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

you could swap the 2 items

`if (do shell script "spctl --status") contains "disabled"`

assuming the returned string is "assessments disabled", and there's only 1 item to check.